# Safari not scaling bullet images

Tags: css, xhtml, safari

When you zoom in on a page in Safari and the bullets have images assigned to them, the images don't scale with the text.   If you zoom in on a page in FF the bullet images will scale.

Is there a way to do make that happen in Safari without using background images?

Comment: Are you using list-type-image, or a background image?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a background image instead of list-style-image:

- Change your list-style-type to `none`
- Style the list item (or if there's an anchor, style the anchor) to have a background-image
- Set the background-repeat to `no-repeat`
- Set the padding-left of the LI to accommodate the background-image
- If needed, adjust the background-position

Something like this:

```
background-image:url(Bullet.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:30px;
margin-left:-30px;
```

Comment: so safari just isn't able to scale bullet images when they're set through list-style-image?

Comment: Seems not. Background images give you more control over the positioning of bullets anyways.